# Адаптивная верстка с Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, bootstrap4

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так что бы на мобильной версии 
заголовок страницы был одного размера, а на компьютерной версии другого размера.

**Например:**

На мобильной версии:

```html
<h5>Tittle</h5>
```

На компьютерной:

```html
<h1 class="display-1">Tittle</h1>
```

Дело в том, что моя надпись (заголовок) вылазит за границы сайта при уменьшении его до мобильной версии и поэтому я хочу узнать - можно ли сделать так, что бы при разных размерах экрана будет по-разному высвечиваться моя информация?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать средствами [медиа запросов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) CSS. Контрольные точки Bootstrap 4:

- xs <576px
- sm ≥576px
- md ≥768px
- lg ≥992px
- xl ≥1200px

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 60px;
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Tittle</h1>
```